# jQuery and Unicode characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling a .txt file from a jquery ajax call. It has some special characters like `±`. This `±` is a delimiter for a set of array; data I want to split out and push into a JavaScript array.

It is not treated as `±` symbol when interpreted like this.

How do I get that data as just like browser content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `escape()` value to split a string. for ± i found two values (maybe there are more?).

```
var string = escape('test±test2±test3');
var split = string.split('%C2%B1');

alert(split); // test,test2,test3

// %B1%0A is the value i found for ±
// %C2%B1 is the value escape() gives me when i just copy and paste that char :)
```

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you encode your text file using [JSON](http://www.json.org/) ? Much more easier, as it already is javascript.

Use JQuery's [getJSON()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) method, and the file contents will directly be parsed into an array.